# c function pointer & user defined function identifier collision

Tags: c, function-pointers

i tested this simple program of function pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
void ptr();
void fun()
{
    printf("fun() is called\n");
}
void ptr()
{
    printf("ptr() is called\n");
}
int main()
{
  void(*ptr)();
  ptr=fun;
  ptr();        // Why it works fine?
  //(ptr)();
  void(*a)()=fun;
  (*a)();
  _getch();
  return 0; 
}
```

output:

```
fun() is called

fun() is called
```

I have a question that why the function call statement
ptr();
won't call user defined function ptr(), but calls fun() function?
Why parentheses around ptr isn't necessary?
What changes my program will require so my program displays output as following.

```
ptr() is called

fun() is called
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you define a local variable `ptr` inside `main`, it **shadows** the same name function `ptr` which is global. So when you call `ptr()`, it's the local function pointer `ptr` that is called.

To make the function `ptr` being called, you need to make sure the local variable `ptr` is out of scope, as this artificial example:

```
int main()
{
    {
      void(*ptr)();
      ptr=fun;
    }
    ptr();
}
```

Comment: This is the "what you don't know shouldn't hurt you" principle. If it were an error then adding functions to existing libraries would be a nightmare of breakage in existing code. If global names overrode local names the outcome would be worse (local being (potentially) silently re-directed. Given the eagerness of C++ to use singleton constructors and otherwise enthusiastically perform conversions to match prototypes I have to say I'm not convinced it's a principle that has been entirely respected and every time it's weakened quality is impaired.

Answer (score 2):

It is an application of the usual scoping rules; local variables hide global variables of the same name.

Or, more accurately, variables defined in an inner scope hide variables of the same name in any outer scopes.

And scopes are basically controlled by sets of braces around blocks of statements (simplifying a bit).

You can get GCC to warn you about such problems with `-Wshadow`.

The other part of the issue is that you can call functions via a pointer to function in (at least) two ways:

```
(*ptr_to_function)();    // Pre-standard notation
ptr_to_function();       // Notation allowed by standard C
```

So the call `ptr();` is identical to `(*ptr)();` in your program.

---

> What changes does my program require to display:
>
> ```
> ptr() is called
> fun() is called
> ```

The simplest change is to remove the line `void (*ptr)() = fun;`.

You could also do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fun(void)
{
    printf("fun() is called\n");
}
void ptr(void)
{
    printf("ptr() is called\n");
}
int main(void)
{
  void (*xyz)(void) = ptr;
  void (*ptr)(void) = fun;
  xyz();
  ptr();
  return 0; 
}
```